# How to change a macro value depending on a text field which is filled in userform?

Tags: vba, automation, ms-word, userform

Consider I have a paragraph:
Our team is working on **five** (5) projects

Where **five** is a fill field in a userform.

How do we show the number form of five in brackets beside it?

I tried by creating a macro for the conversion word form of a number to number form.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub get_number(mstr)

ones = Array("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine")
ones_num = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    
teens = Array("eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen")
teens_num = Array(11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)
        
tys = Array("twenty", "thirty", "fourty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety")
tys_num = Array(20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90)

arr = Split(mstr, " ")
    
get_number = -1 word_index = UBound(arr) 'start from last word

parsed_value = -1
    
'check first word in ONES
For i = 0 To UBound(ones) 'search through ones
    If ones(i) = arr(word_index) Then '1st word found and it is ONES, for example it is FIVE
        parsed_value = ones_num(i)
        If UBound(arr) = 0 Then
            'there is no second word
            GoTo end_of_code
        Else
            'go and read second word
            GoTo second_word
        End If
    End If
Next i
         
'check first word in TEENS
For i = 0 To UBound(teens)
    If teens(i) = arr(word_index) Then '1st word found and it is TEENS, for example it is FIVETEEN
        parsed_value = teens_num(i)
           
        If UBound(arr) = 0 Then
            'there is no second word
            GoTo end_of_code
        Else
            'go and read second word
            GoTo second_word
        End If
    End If
Next i
    
'check first word in TYS
For i = 0 To UBound(tys)
    If tys(i) = arr(word_index) Then '1st word found and it is TYS, for example it is FIFTY
        parsed_value = tys_num(i)
        If UBound(arr) = 0 Then
            'there is no second word
            GoTo end_of_code
        Else
            'go and read second word
            GoTo second_word
        End If
    End If
Next i
    
'check if first word is HUNDRED
If arr(word_index) = "hundred" Then
    parsed_value = 100
    If UBound(arr) = 0 Then
        'there is no second word
        GoTo end_of_code
    Else
        'go and read second word
        GoTo second_word
    End If

    'if first word not found, then jump to end of code without parsing second word, no point
    If parsed_value < 0 Then GoTo end_of_code

second_word: 'start analysing second word
    word_index = word_index - 1
    second_found = False
    If parsed_value < 10 Then
        '1st word was in ONES
        'check first word in TYS
        For i = 0 To UBound(tys)
            If tys(i) = arr(word_index) Then '1st word found and it is TYS, for example it is FIFTY
                parsed_value = tys_num(i) + parsed_value
                second_found = True
                If UBound(arr) = 1 Then
                    GoTo end_of_code 
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    
end_of_code:
    'end of code finish things here
        
    If parsed_value > 0 Then get_number = parsed_value
      
End Sub
```

The fill field (mstr; eg:five) is in another macro.

How do I connect these two things?

Comment: There is already a field format to convert a number to text: `\* cardtext` Instead, have the user type in the number and use a REF field formatted for text to spell it out as a word. No vba needed or your vba input box that collects the number can update the ref field. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#Switch

Comment: But here we need to change a word to a number